# PICKIT3 unavailable on MPLAB X IDE

Tags: pic, mplabx, pickit

## What I want to achieve

To write a program to a PIC microchip using PICKIT3 and MPLAB X IDE.

## Issue

- PICKIT3 not found on Device Manager
- No compilers found on MPLAB X IDE

## Environment

- Windows 10
- PICKIT3
- MPLAB X IDE v6.10
- PIC16F84A

## What I did

I connected the PICKIT3 to 3 different USB ports and there didn't seem to be any PICKIT3 on Deivce Manager. 2 of the ports were directly on the mother board of my PC. When I connected the PICKIT3, the power lamp was green and active one was blue. The status one flashed red and turned off.

I ran MPLAB X IDE and I got the following message.

[image]

I downloaded MPLAB XC16 Compiler from [this page](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-xc-compilers) and installed it. The bin directory was added to PATH. When I tried to create a project to test writing to the PIC, MPLAB threw an error.

[image]

So I decided to add the compiler from Tools>Options>Embedded>Build Tools>Add according to [this page](https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/How-to-add-a-compiler-to-MPLAB-X-toolchain). However, MPLAB said "Base directory does not contain a toolchain."

[image]

## What I searched so far

I checked the two pages below which didn't help me so much.

- https://forum.microchip.com/s/topic/a5C3l000000McFYEA0/t377092
- https://forum.microchip.com/s/topic/a5C3l000000MY30EAG/t360938

I'm kind of at a deadend. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like from your screenshots the path has gotten mangled (note the `¥` character rather than `\ ` as a path separator). As to why the PICKit is not found, seems like an unrelated hardware issue. Unfortunately questions on use of electronic devices are off topic. Probably better off asking for support on the microchip forum.

Comment: You need XC8, not XC16. XC16 is for 16-bit PICs (like the PIC24 & dsPIC series), not 8-bit pics like your PIC16.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Thanks for you suggestion. I'll do so.

Comment: @brhans I just thought 16 in PIC16 says it's an 8-bit PIC. Thanks.

Comment: PIC10, PIC12, PIC16 & PIC18 are all 8-bit PICs (and the old obsolete PIC17 too).

Answer (score 2):

MPLAB PICkit 3, MPLAB ICD 3 and several on-board debuggers fail to connect in MPLAB X IDE v6.10. When attempting to connect to these tools through selection in Project Properties, clicking Apply or OK will generate the error

> “Failed to download firmware. Connection Failed”.

Fix: Install the MPLAB X IDE 6.10 patch. Do this by installing the 5 plugins suggested in the popup notification. These will enable MPLAB PICkit 3, MPLAB ICD 3, onboard debugging for certain eval boards and fix connectivity issues.

The 5 plugins are:

- PICkit3 Tool [1.0 -> 1.1]
- ICD3 Tool [1.0 -> 1.1]
- PK3OB [1.0 -> 1.1]
- PKOBSKDE [1.0 -> 1.1]
- MPLABComm [1.1 -> 1.2]

Also find the Plugins by selecting Tools > Plugins > Updates.